# How to safely update office-js-dependencies in react outlook-web-addin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a react outlook addin and want to know how to update the addin to the latest office-js-dependencies. There's a [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/update-your-javascript-api-for-office-and-manifest-schema-version) but I can't make head nor tail of it.

I think I have to change the versions in my package.json. But there's nothing about it in the documentation.

Here are the dev-deps in my package.json:

```
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.37",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.8",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.0.3",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^3.0.17",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.4.10",
    "office-addin-lint": "^1.0.15",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.4.13",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.0.10",
```

Should I keep them up to date manually?
In my manifest.xml are the links to the newest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on those dependencies, I'm assuming your add-in project was created by [yo office](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office).

Updating those dev dependencies (via `npm install`) will only affect the development experience and not the runtime of the add-in. The main benefit to updating the types dependencies will be as new APIs are added, you will be able to call them from TypeScript code. And if you use the [manifest validation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office#validate-manifestxml) functionality provided by yo office, updating the dependencies will include any updates to the manifest schema used for validation.

The [linked documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/update-your-javascript-api-for-office-and-manifest-schema-version) refers to two updates that you won't need to do because the add-in created by yo office already uses manifest schema version 1.1. In particular, so long as Office.js is loaded [from the CDN location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn), your add-in will always use the latest version of the Office.js API.